# Calculating Euclidean Distance for Rolling Time Windows of labelled data in Python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

I have a sample dataframe with labels and timestamps like this:

```
            timestamps labels
0  2023-08-01 00:00:00     A
1  2023-08-01 03:00:00     B
2  2023-08-01 06:00:00     C
3  2023-08-01 09:00:00     A
4  2023-08-01 12:00:00     B
5  2023-08-01 15:00:00     C
6  2023-08-01 18:00:00     A
7  2023-08-01 21:00:00     B
```

I would like to get the counts of the N (10 here) most frequent labels of the overall dataset, in an array. Then I would like to look at the dataframe in a rolling time window of say like '14D' and get an array of the counts of the N most frequent labels in this window. The 11th element in both arrays will just be 1 - normalized sum of array (can ignore this part). Then I wanna calculate the euclidean distance between the 2 arrays and plot it against the timestamps.

So this solution works, but since I have a very large dataset, iterating through the rolling window takes a long time. Also, I have to ignore all the distances calculated till the timestamps reaches the first time window. Is there a better, faster way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

def get_label_array(label_series, top_N=10):
    label_counts = label_series.value_counts().head(top_N)
    other_count = len(label_series) - label_counts.sum()
    
    label_arr = label_counts.values
    label_arr = np.append(label_arr, other_count)
    normalized_label_arr = label_arr / np.sum(label_arr)
    return normalized_label_arr

def calculate_rolling_dist(df, timestamps, time_window='14D', top_N=10):
    datetimestamps = pd.to_datetime(timestamps)
    df.set_index(datetimestamps, inplace=True)
    top_N_lft = get_label_array(df['labels'], top_N)
    rolling_result = []
    rolling_ts = []
    for window_start in df.index[:-1]:
        rolling_ts.append(window_start)   
        print(window_start)   
        window_end = window_start + pd.Timedelta(time_window)
        window_data = df.loc[window_start:window_end]
        if len(window_data) > 0:
            lft = get_label_array(window_data['labels'], top_N)
            if len(lft) >= 10:
                rolling_result.append(euclidean(top_N_lft,lft))
    return np.array(rolling_result), np.array(rolling_ts)
```

Comment: Can we say that `timestamps` have some frequency, sort of 3 hours as in your example data, or the time delta between neighboring points can change?

Comment: The time delta between successive points can change. I am working with a huge dataset and have millions of rows across 6 months, time delta between successive points is generally less than 3 seconds.

Comment: What about labels, are they just letters, as in the example, or strings of different length and content?

Comment: Just single Capital letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas 1.5.1` `numpy 1.23.4` `numba 0.57.1` `python 3.11.0`

---

## Rolling window aggregation

Without asking the meaning of what exactly you are trying to do, I'll try to answer purely on execution technique.

So, let's prepare some data to work with. I'm gonna assume that you have a sequence of symbols, e.g. a capital Latin letter, indexed by timestamps with a predefined frequency, e.g. 3 hours. The last assumption will matter at the very end when we get rid of the index to work exclusively in Numpy. As for symbols, I'm assuming they are categorical values which can be replaced by numbers in a fixed range.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from string import ascii_uppercase
from timeit import Timer
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(seed=0)


total = 3*8*14*10    # 8x3hours(1day) * 14days * 10times 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.date_range('2023', periods=total, freq='3H')
    , 'label': rng.choice([*ascii_uppercase], size=total)
})
```

Also, I hope you will forgive me for allowing myself to use other names:

- `get_label_array` I call `nfrequent`
- `calculate_rolling_dist` I call `rolling_distance`
- `top_N` I call just `n`

### Pandas' rolling windows

We can simplify the first function returning a limited frequency table with [pandas.Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), note the `normalize=True` parameter. Also, I'm delegating Numpy and Pandas as much iterations as possible:

```
def nfrequent(seq, n):
    '''get n most frequent items in discending order
    with normalized frequency and all the rest at the end'''
    vc = seq.value_counts(normalize=True)   # ascending=False by default
    return pd.concat([
        vc.iloc[:n],
        pd.Series({'rest': vc.iloc[n:].sum()})
    ])

def rolling_distance(seq, window='14D', n=10):
    total_nfreq = nfrequent(seq, n)
    n = len(total_nfreq) - 1    # in case if total_nfreq is short
    return seq.map(ord).rolling(window).agg(
        lambda x: (
            euclidean(total_nfreq, window_nfreq)
            if len((window_nfreq:=nfrequent(x, n))) > n
            else np.nan
         ) 
    )
```

Notes on the code:

- A function should assume that all dates have already been converted to `datetime`, because in general we can't predict the format of the date passed as a string.
- We can assume as well that data passed to the second function are a `Series` of symbols with timestamps as indexes.
- I think a default value of a parameter should be declared once in an external function to avoid confusion. You define `top_N=10` in both, which is a source of headaches in the future.
- I used `seq.map(ord)` to make data aggregation with a custom function work on rolling windows. Otherwise we need to iterate over windows in the outer loop.

Let's note the speed on the test data:

```
seq = df.set_index('timestamp').squeeze()
ans_pd = rolling_distance(seq)    # use this to check with other results
print(Timer(lambda: rolling_distance(seq)).autorange())
```

On my hardware, the task took 3.47 seconds to complete. It looks too much. The outer for-loop is even less productive (3.97 sec). So let's see for other options.

### A little more Numpy

Let's try to minimize Pandas in the `nfrequent`, and get rid of if-else statement in rolling aggregation. Also, I decided that `seq.map(ord)` is better out the `rolling_distance` function:

```
def nfrequent(seq, n, count_unique=26):    # 26 is len(string.asci_uppercase)
    '''get n most frequent items in discending order, n < count_unique
    with normalized frequency and all the rest at the end'''
    counts = np.bincount(seq, minlength=count_unique)
    counts[::-1].sort()    # sort inplace in reversed order
    counts[n] = counts[n:].sum()
    return counts[:n+1] / counts[:n+1].sum()

def rolling_distance(seq, window='14D', n=10):
    total_nfreq = nfrequent(seq, n)
    return seq.rolling(window).agg(    
        lambda window: euclidean(total_nfreq, nfrequent(window, n))
    )
```

Check the performance and save the result:

```
seq = df.set_index('timestamp').squeeze().map(ord)
ans_np = rolling_distance(seq)
print(Timer(lambda: rolling_distance(seq)).autorange())
```

The performance on my side is much better this time, 358 ms against 3.5 sec previously. Can Numba help? Not the right time. There will be problems with `pandas.Series`, and because of the hassle of converting data to `numpy.ndarray`, performance will be degraded. Let's figure out another way to create rolling windows without Pandas.

### Numpy tricks with slicing

What if we consider a sequence of labels as a two-dimensional array? Consider it as follows:

- the first index of this array is the window number;
- the second is the number of the element in the window.

We can accomplish this with [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). For this purpose, we need data with a certain frequency so that all windows of a given time interval have the same number of labels. As an additional advantage, we can now to use step to low down the number of windows to loop over:

```
def nfrequent(seq, n, count_unique=26):    # 26 is len(string.asci_uppercase)
    '''get n most frequent items in discending order, n < count_unique
    with normalized frequency and all the rest at the end'''
    #counts = np.zeros(count_unique)
    counts = np.bincount(seq, minlength=count_unique)
    counts[::-1].sort()    # sort inplace in reversed order
    counts[n] = counts[n:].sum()
    return counts[:n+1] / counts[:n+1].sum()

def rolling_distance(arr, window, step=1, n=10):
    windows = strided_view(seq, window)
    total_nfreq = nfrequent(seq, n)
    distance = np.empty(windows.shape[0] ,dtype=float)
    for i in range(distance.size):
        distance[i] = euclidean(total_nfreq, nfrequent(windows[i], n))
    return distance

def strided_view(arr, window, step=1):
    n = arr.size
    itemsize = arr.itemsize
    ksteps = 1 + (n - window) // step
    return as_strided(
        arr
        , shape=(ksteps, window)
        , strides=(itemsize*step, itemsize)
        , writeable=False
    )
```

Now we prepare data as a numpy array and parameters of a sliding window as integer numbers (i.e. we transform strings like `'14D'` into a number of labels to take like one window):

```
# map the labels by numbers from 0 to 25
seq = df.set_index('timestamp').squeeze().map(ord) - ord('A')

# save the timestamps in index to restore lately if needed
index, seq = seq.index, seq.to_numpy()

freq = pd.Timedelta('3H')
interval = pd.Timedelta('14D')
window = interval // freq        # number of items in a window

ans_strided = rolling_distance(seq, window)  # save the data to compare
print(Timer(lambda: rolling_distance(seq, window))).autorange())
```

This time I see the performance was somewhat better, 120 ms against 358 ms and 3.5 sec in the previous times.

### Numpy stryde tricks and Numba

The code above can be adapted to run it with Numba:

```
@njit
def nfrequent(seq, n, count_unique=26):    # 26 is len(string.asci_uppercase)
    '''get n most frequent items in discending order, n < count_unique
    with normalized frequency and all the rest at the end'''
    #counts = np.zeros(count_unique)
    counts = np.bincount(seq, minlength=count_unique)
    counts[::-1].sort()    # sort inplace in reversed order
    counts[n] = counts[n:].sum()
    return counts[:n+1] / counts[:n+1].sum()

@njit
def rolling_distance(windows, n=10):     # pass strided windows as a parameter
    total_nfreq = nfrequent(seq, n)
    distance = np.empty(windows.shape[0], dtype=float)
    for i in range(distance.size):
        delta = total_nfreq - nfrequent(windows[i], n)
        distance[i] = np.sqrt(delta @ delta)    
    return distance

def strided_view(arr, width, step=1):
    n = arr.size
    itemsize = arr.itemsize
    ksteps = 1 + (n - width) // step
    return as_strided(
        arr
        , shape=(ksteps, width)
        , strides=(itemsize*step, itemsize)
        , writeable=False
    )

# prepare data, collect result, check performance
seq = df.set_index('timestamp').squeeze().map(ord) - ord('A')
index, seq = seq.index, seq.to_numpy()

# we have the test data with a frequency 3 hours
# and the time interval of interest is 14 days
freq = pd.Timedelta('3H')
interval = pd.Timedelta('14D')
width = interval // freq

windows = strided_view(seq, width)
ans_numba_strided = rolling_distance(windows)
print(Timer(lambda: rolling_distance(windows))).autorange())
```

*NOTE: I couldn't use `euclidean` with Numba in [nopython mode](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode) so replaced it with a direct analogy*

This time I've got 4.76 ms on the test data, which is quite better then all the others.

### Uneven distribution of data over time

If the data is unevenly distributed over time, we might try to classify them into time bins, e.g.:

```
# transform seq in a sequence of numbers in range(26)
seq = df.set_index('timestamp').squeeze().map(ord) - ord('A')

timebin = pd.Timedelta('6H')
start, stop = seq.index[[0, -1]]
nbins = (2*(stop-start)+timebin) // (2*timebin)    # cover all the data
nlabels = len(ascii_uppercase)

data = np.zeros((nbins, nlabels), dtype=float)

for i in range(nbins):
    data[i, :] = np.bincount(
        seq[start+i*timebin : start+(i+1)*timebin]
        , minlength=26
    )
```

Now we can slide along bins, i.e. first index of data, with a fixed window shape `(bins_in_interval, num_of_letters)` to collect distributions of letters over given period.